# Como faço para a PDO listar o Array com os Types Corretos?

Tags: php, array, pdo

No MySQL gravo dados em uma tabela definindo alguns campos como `int` ou `float`, mas quando faço um `select` no banco de dados via PDO o `array` vem tudo como string. 
Tem alguma função que força a retornar o type de acordo com que esta no banco?

Veja:

```
 array(13) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(4) "1713"
  ["id_shop_default"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["id_envio_default"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["regiao"]=>
  string(19) "SAO PAULO - CAPITAL"
  ["cep_inicio"]=>
  string(9) "01000-001"
  ["cep_fim"]=>
  string(9) "05999-999"
  ["peso_inicial"]=>
  string(5) "0.000"
  ["peso_final"]=>
  string(5) "1.000"
  ["valor"]=>
  string(5) "22.70"
  ["prazo_entrega"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["ad_valorem"]=>
  string(4) "1.00"
  ["kg_adicional"]=>
  string(4) "1.72"
  ["created"]=>
  string(19) "2016-09-19 17:11:09"
}
```

o valor mesmo é `float`!

Desde já agradeço.

Edit:

```
<?php    

try{    

  $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false);

  // Faz conexão com banco de daddos
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=banco","root", "123456", $opt);


}catch(PDOException $e){
  // Caso ocorra algum erro na conexão com o banco, exibe a mensagem
  echo 'Falha ao conectar no banco de dados: '.$e->getMessage();
  die;
}

try {

  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

  $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM transportadora");
  $linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($linha);
  echo "</pre>";


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código em que vc cria o PDO.

Comment: @rray Editei o Post e coloquei o código completo já com as modificações, mas sem sucesso, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Veja no phpinfo() se vc tem o mysqlnd instalado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` está marcado como `false` essa opção pode ser aplicado via `setAttribute()` ou direto no construtor do PDO.

```
$opt = array(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false);
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=base', 'usuario', 'senha', $opt);
```